# How do I override the title with the username?

Tags: views

I am creating a view that will be visible under /user/%/blog, and I am trying to override the view's title with the username (e.g. *kiamlaluno's blog*), but the description of the field doesn't tell me what I can use to override the title.

> [image: screenshot]

I only get I can use Twig syntax, but that doesn't help much.

I used *Content: Authored by* as contextual filter. I also added *author* as relationship, but I didn't see any change.

How can I override the title with the name of the user authoring the nodes being shown from the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch the node's uid argument plugin to [`Drupal\user\Plugin\views\argument\Uid`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Plugin!views!argument!Uid.php/class/Uid/8.2.x), and get the same behaviour from that field instead. It would take a small amount of code in a custom module.

```
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['node_field_data']['uid']['argument']['id'] = 'user_uid';
}
```

Alternatively, if passing the author's username in the view URL is not a problem for you, since you have the author relationship set up, you can use the `User: User ID` field for your filter instead of the one you're currently using. Because of the way its handler treats requests for titles, using `{{ arguments.uid }}` in the "Override title" field will actually provide you with the username(s) instead of the ID(s).

Comment: If I set _User: Name_ as contextual filter, the view expects I use it for /user/kiamlaluno/blog, while Drupal uses /user/1 for the user profiles.

Comment: Hmmm, understood. So what you need is a contextual filter that works off the user ID, but makes the associated username available in the arguments. Sounds reasonable. I'll have a dig in the code

Comment: @kiamlaluno Took a while but got something, updated

Comment: And `{{ raw_arguments.uid }}` gives me the user ID, if I really need it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make *Fields* the format used by the view

> [image]

Alternatively, if you are using the rendered entity row plugin check the *Force using fields* in *Format | Settings*

2. In *Relationship*, add *Content author*

   - Checkmark ☑ *Require relationship*
3. In *Fields*, add *Name*

   - Checkmark ☑ *Exclude from display*
   - Uncheck ☐ *Link to the user*
4. For *Title* put `{{ name }}'s blog`

> [image]

You could put it as contextual filter; even though `{{ name }}` is not listed as a replacement pattern, it works (as long as you do step 1, 2, and 3)

> [image]

### Result

> [image]

#### Bonus

If you want to capitalize the first letter of the user name use `{{ name|capitalize }}'s blog`.

You can also add a *Rendered Entity* as a field.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: This approach is quite limited, and unintuitive. It relies on using the field row plugin, which means it doesn't work with the rendered entity row plugin, or any others.

Comment: @Clive `unintuitive` if you're used to solving everything by code not unintuitive at all if you're used to coming up with non coding solutions.

Comment: Nope. Read the first paragraph of my answer. No code involved, problem solved without restrictions

Comment: @Nope, read my edited answer.

Comment: ...which is unintuitive, when you already have a "Rendered Entity" row style.  Not to mention more effort, and more to maintain.Thanks for proving my point.

Comment: @Clive `already have a "Rendered Entity"` I do not since I am using [Fields as my format...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ipuOQ.jpg) not content, when you use fields there is no rendered entity unless you add it as a field.

Comment: But why would you intentionally restrict yourself to that when the core devs have already given you a proper way to do it? The user_uid argument plugin doesn't convert the title to username by accident, the OP's use case is the reason it exists. Don't use a screwdriver to hammer a nail. Especially when you have s a hammer in the other hand :)

Comment: @Clive I approached it from a non User ID way, IMO `user/1` looks ugly, I like using path auto so it's `user/admin`, hence your answer is better if people want to use UID, but if they don't, you're answer is no good for them.

Comment: I don't understand - the OP's requirement is for user **ID**, not name, in the path. You're arguing that user name could be used, fine, everyone's got an opinion. But yet instead of making that change you've abused the field plugin to force a token into scope for the user uid argument/contextual filter? You haven't switched the contextual filter to be based on the user name field itself (see the first revision of my answer), which would actually impose the change you've suggsted rather than doing nothing at all? Can you not see how flawed that logic is?

Comment: And just to confirm, the first revision of my answer covered the _you're answer is no good for them._ part of your objection. The OP explicitly stated, as you can still see in the comments, that's incorrect for their requirements. So I removed it, as it was wrong.

Comment: User name has `{{ arguments.uid }}` ok I see.

Comment: No need to delete this! The approach is still technically valid, it could help someone out. I'm sorry if you feel like I've pressured you to get rid of this, that wasn't my intention. I just wanted to clarify the points, I spent about 2 hours looking into this last night so I'm very familiar with how this part of Views works now

Comment: I meant user Name has `{{ arguments.name }}` ok I see

Comment: Awesome trick! Thank you! @Clive To use this with the rendered entity row plugin check the `Force using fields` in format settings.

Comment: This answer is useful in the case somebody isn't able to write a module or doesn't want to do so. There are users who prefer doing things from the UI, and this answer helps them.